# limit item entry C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

need to limit the ammount of items that can be entered into the array to 5. Tought i would use a do while loop but it just continues even after the 5 items have been entered. Any help would be appreciated

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <string>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <array>

using namespace std;
    string sItems[4] = {};
    string sChoice = "";
    int iItemPrice[4] = {};
    int iNumOfItems = 0;
    int iMenuChoice = 0;
    int iCount = 0;


int main()
{
    cout << "--------- Welcome to the program ---------\n\n Please pick from an option below: \n 1: Enter new items \n 2: Change item prices \n 3: Input sold items \n 4: Receipt for previous items sold\n ";
    cin >> iMenuChoice;



        switch (iMenuChoice)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            do {
                cout << "--------- ENTER NEW ITEMS ---------\n\nPlease enter the item Name: ";
                cin >> sItems[iCount];
                cout << "\nPlease enter the price of: " << sItems[iCount] << "\n";
                cin >> iItemPrice[iCount];
                cout << "\nWould you like to enter another item? Y/N \n";
                cin >> sChoice;
                if (sChoice == "Y" || sChoice == "y")
                {
                    ++iCount;
                    ++iNumOfItems;
                }
            } while (sChoice == "Y" || sChoice == "y" || iNumOfItems < 5);

            cout << "you have entered the maximum ammount of items";
        }
        }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you ever seen any code like `sChoice == "Y"||"y"` in your C++ textbook?

Comment: Replace `iCount + 1 && iNumOfItems + 1` with `++iCount; ++iNumOfItems;`

Comment: is what i have been using what is the correct way? @NeilButterworth

Comment: Please stop using broken notation. "iChoice" tells me nothing about the purpose of the variable; "sChoice" doesn't either. Use real meaningful names instead.

Comment: and post all your code. We can't see whether you've included the right headers, what on Earth `_getch()` is meant to be and why you're using that in C++, whether you're compiling in a way that would warn you about any mistakes you might be making, etc.

Comment: Maybe it is because `while (sChoice == "Y" || sChoice == "y" || iNumOfItems < 5);` checks the sChoice first, and if  either one of the first two yields true, the whole condition became true regardless the value of !NumOfItem is. Perhaps what you want is this `while ((sChoice == "Y" || sChoice == "y" ) && iNumOfItems < 5);`

Comment: If you want to *"limit the ammount of items that can be entered into the array to 5"*, I guess you want an array of 5 items too, to store them. So you should declare it as `int iItemPrice[5] = {};`. Anyways, consider using `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The loop condition `sChoice == "Y" || sChoice == "y" || iNumOfItems < 5` means:

- Loop as long as user answers "Y"
- But at least 5 times regardless of user answer

If you want some other logic, like loop up to 5 times, then you can reflect that in the code.

Also check for failures. If you input a character when `cin` expects a number, it will enter a failed state and all subsequent input attempts will fail.

```
            do {
                cout << "--------- ENTER NEW ITEMS ---------\n\nPlease enter the item Name: ";
                cin >> sItems[iCount];
                cout << "\nPlease enter the price of: " << sItems[iCount] << "\n";
                if (!(cin >> iItemPrice[iCount]))
                    break;
                cout << "\nWould you like to enter another item? Y/N \n";
                cin >> sChoice;
                ++iCount;
                ++iNumOfItems;
            } while ((sChoice == "Y" || sChoice == "y") && iNumOfItems < 5);
```

And increase the array size from `4` to `5` if you want to support 5 items:

```
string sItems[5];
int iItemPrice[5];
```

Comment: You probably also need to change `if (sChoice == "Y")` to `if (sChoice == "Y" || sChoice == "y")`

Comment: Please edit your question and post the complete (but minimal) application, including the main function, all declarations, etc.